Parsing Palo Alto traffic syslogs with RegEx to make JSON for LimaCharlie Adapter
I am trying to parse Syslog from a Palo Alto firewall to JSON.
I am doing this on the LimaCharlie Adapter.
My problem is that it works for most messages, but a few SYSTEM messages gives "invalid-json".
VALID
677 <14>1 2024-10-08T09:36:54+02:00 PA-440 - - - - 1,2024/10/08 09:36:54,021201133296,TRAFFIC,end,2561,2024/10/08 09:36:54,10.10.10.103,23.30.01.208,192.168.92.158,23.30.01.208,rule1,,,quic,vsys1,trust,untrust,ethernet1/2,ethernet1/1,LFP LimaCharlie,2024/10/08 09:36:54,100868,1,65311,443,63282,443,0x400019,udp,allow,6780,3085,3695,17,2024/10/08 09:34:22,30,any,,7408146363089122356,0x0,10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255,Norway,,7,10,aged-out,0,0,0,0,,PA-440,from-policy,,,0,,0,,N/A,0,0,0,0,a6854971-45bb-499a-86fd-30008807b6e1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2024-10-08T09:36:54.055+02:00,,,infrastructure,networking,browser-based,1,tunnel-other-application,,quic,no,no,0

INVALID
352 <11>1 2024-10-08T15:06:40+02:00 PA-440 - - - - 1,2024/10/08 15:06:39,021201133296,SYSTEM,url-filtering,2561,2024/10/08 15:06:40,,url-cloud-connection-failure,,0,0,general,high,"Cloud is not ready, There was no update from the cloud in the last 59155 minutes.",7408146363088729971,0x0,0,0,0,0,,PA-440-ACDC-Lab,0,0,2024-10-08T15:06:40.278+02:00

My Regex:
(?P<priority>\\d+) <(?P<facility>\\d+)>1 (?P<receive_time>\\S+) (?P<device_name>\\S+) (?P<field1>-) (?P<field2>-) (?P<field3>-) (?P<field4>-) (?P<assoc_id>\\d+),(?P<time_generated>\\d{4}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}),(?P<serialnumber>\\d+),(?P<subtype>[^,]+),(?P<action>\\w+),(?P<sessionid>\\d+),(?P<time_received>\\d{4}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})

The entire LimaCharlie Adapter command looks like this:
sudo ./lc_adapter syslog client_options.identity.installation_key=1-2-3-4-5 client_options.identity.oid=6-7-8-9-10 client_options.platform=json client_options.hostname=traffic2 client_options.sensor_seed_key=traffic2 port=514 iface=0.0.0.0 is_udp=false "client_options.mapping.parsing_re=(?P<priority>\\d+) <(?P<facility>\\d+)>1 (?P<receive_time>\\S+) (?P<device_name>\\S+) (?P<field1>-) (?P<field2>-) (?P<field3>-) (?P<field4>-) (?P<assoc_id>\\d+),(?P<time_generated>\\d{4}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}),(?P<serialnumber>\\d+),(?P<subtype>[^,]+),(?P<action>\\w+),(?P<sessionid>\\d+),(?P<time_received>\\d{4}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})" client_options.mapping.event_type_path=subtype

What is wrong with my Regex?

change (?P<action>\w+) to (?P<action>[\w-]+)? See here. Issue in your INVALID example seems to be, that "url-filtering" is not matched because \w+ cannot match a "-"
